# Dynamic members allocation in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm confused with where to dynamically allocate (QFile* and QTextStream*) in the constructor (as it is illustrated below) or in the method itself, if a method GetCurrentStream() ought to change the value *stream.

**header file**

```
class QLogger {
public:
   explicit QLogger();
   ~QLogger();
   QTextStream& GetCurrenStream();
private:
   QFile *file;
   QTextStream *stream;
};
```

and in related .cpp

```
QLogger::QLogger() {
   file = new QFile;
   stream = new QTextStream;
}

~QLogger() {
   delete file;
   delete stream;
}

QTextStream& GetCurrenStream() {
  ...
  return *stream;
}
```

And where to release the storage in the destructor?

Comment: I would prefer constructor initialization list. I would also provide or prevent copy construction and assignment because as it is now you can have future bad surprises. It is common bug pattern.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, if calling your class QLogger is a good idea. Q* are Qt classes. Technically no problem. But maybe Digia introduces a class QLogger with their next release. This might then become somewhat confusing.

Comment: Also I would not name my classes starting with Q as that would distinguish it from Qt's own classes.

Comment: Well, can you illustrate it on example what have you said on your first advice? Thank you.

Comment: it's not *necessary* to use pointers. You could go with `QFile file; QTextStream stream;` and get rid of constructors/destructors.

Comment: @elgolondrino: If you are unfamiliar to those concepts I think you would simplify your class not using pointers at all. Do not declare your data members as pointers. Everything will be easier for you. You do not even need a constructor or a destructor. I mean change QFile* to QFile. Do the same with QTextStream. I think compile time dependency is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, but I'm writtiing log to an server app. using the objects of Logger class and worried about memory leak and dangling pointers issue!

Comment: I would like to add that using explicit don't give you anything in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to provide your object with all the necessary data the moment it will be constructed, you should put all initialization in the constructor, for it creates the actual object. This way, you make sure, that your object will be ready when you use it.
If you are not using any special pattern, your getters should not create the objects they return, but rather a reference, as you did in `GetCurrentStream()`.

Secondly, with the destructor, this is the actual place to deallocate memory from allocated objects. If you have deallocation-processes that might be dangerous, you should provide an extra method for this, because if something fails in the destructor, you'll experience a memory-leak. Also, never throw exceptions in a destructor!

If you need to change a pointer to an object (like in `GetCurrentStream()`, you should rather provide a different method for changing the stream and handle necessary deallocation in this very method).
Also remember to return a reference to a pointer like

```
return *stream; //return reference to actual object, not the pointer!
```

All in all it looks fine, what you did there.

Answer (score 1):

What you did seems about right. You allocate objects in the constructor, and delete them in the destructor.

But, it should not build as is, since `GetCurrentStream()` is supposed to return a reference to the stream object and you are currently returning a pointer.

Something like the code sample below is probably what is missing.

```
QTextStream& GetCurrenStream() {
  ...
  return *stream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using smart pointers to manage your dynamically allocated objects.

In Qt you can use `QScopedPointer` (in C++11 there is also `std::unique_ptr`).

(Also as mentioned in comments above: Q* names are basically reserved by Qt stuff.)

```
class Logger {
public:
   Logger();
   QTextStream& getCurrenStream();
private:
   QScopedPointer<QFile> file;
   QScopedPointer<QTextStream> stream;
};

Logger::Logger()
    : file(new QFile)
    , stream(new QTextStream)
{
}

QTextStream& getCurrenStream() {
  // ...
  return stream.data(); // stream.get() with std::unique_ptr
}
```

Memory is automatically deallocated by smart pointers (with `QSharedPointer` and `std::shared_ptr` there is additionally reference counting so memory is not deallocated while there exist a copy of the shared pointer).

Comment: It's safe in this case. But don't use smart pointers and assign QObject parent for other QObject (you'll get double deallocation).

Comment: If file and stream is initialized in the initialization list one might also consider to declare then 'QFile * const file' and 'QTextStream * const stream'. Of course not if QScopedPointer is used. :-)